# Create Stacked Area Combined with Line Chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm having trouble creating a chart that combines a line chart with a stacked area chart in Tableau Public. I can create the line chart in Tableau, but after that, I don't know how to proceed. Attached is the chart I created in Excel that I am trying to recreate in Tableau.

[Line + Stacked Area Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk5HL.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Look for "dual axis" in the online help or vendor training videos

Answer (score 2):

Make your chart a duel axis chart - to do this you must have at least 2 measures on your shelf - click on the right most measure a select 'Duel axis'. Once you've done this, you'll see that each measure has it's own tab on the Marks shelf, which means you can set different mark types on each - for example one measure can be a bar chart and the second can be a line graph.

Hope that helps,
Ben